# Subqueries in mysql with json

Tags: mysql, json, subquery

I have the following querie...

```
select
    concat(r.origin_id,'.json') as json_name,
    json_object( 'data' ,
        json_object(
            r.origin_id,
            json_object(
                'nome', r.name,
                'header', (SELECT url from realties_images where realty_id = r.realty_id and type_image = 'cover'),
                'cover' ,(SELECT url from realties_images where realty_id = r.realty_id and type_image = 'header'),
                'images', json_arrayagg(
                    json_object('url', ri.url, 'legenda', ri.legend , 'tipo' , ri.type_image_api)
                ),
                'plants' , json_arrayagg(
                    json_object('url', ri.url, 'legenda', ri.legend, 'tipo' , ri.type_image_api)
                )
            )
        )
    )as json
    from realties r
    inner join developers d on r.developer_id = d.developer_id
    inner join realties_images ri on r.realty_id = ri.realty_id
    where r.active = 'yes' and d.active = 'yes' and ri.active = 'yes'
    group by r.origin_id
```

what I need is the following in the array "plants" and "images" I need to do a sub queries with a conditional, how can I do it, because I can not do it.

As for example the subquerie above but it comes a single record and the one that I need will return several

Comment: another thing the subquerie needs to be tied with join with the main query

Comment: If you have additional details, explain them in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Are you using a programming language like PHP or Python to process the query results? It would probably be easier to create the JSON there than in SQL.

Comment: no i MUST use this object but in images and plants i need pass a "WHERE" conditional to filter results

Comment: Can you add example data and the desired result?